# A folder suddenly disapearred

Tags: 12.04, directory, downloads

Today when I download something at website, suddenly jump a tag, ask me there is a problem about ubuntu system, whether continue, I click continue button , then I find my download folder disappear. I don't know what's happen, I restart system. my download folder completely disapear, how I can recovery it. it include many data
Thank you

Comment: I have find it by my browser, and I

Comment: I have find it by my brower and I type find "my files" in terminal by the order "find or cd" It disappear. I can't find it. right now I am not only afraid of I can't recovery it. I also afraid of it actually

Comment: it actually exist at my disk. I can't operate it, but it also occupy my memory

Comment: I don't know what it is. but it seems like completely disaapear like it never exist.

Comment: I get the error message"the folder doesn't exist", I still can't find it, I used every method I know, they are useless

Answer (score 0):

You may
1. accidently pressed <kbd>Delete</kbd>. Looks in *Trash*
2. Accidently renamed .  Search for a file in it from nautilus or locate it from terminal `locate -i filename`.
3. File system corrupted. Check, repair it and recover file `sudo fsck /dev/sdXY`. Recovered files will be stored at LOST+FOUND directory of root of partition. Only root user can access it.
4. Data corrupted by software/hardware malfunction. Recover file by file using data recovery software like `r-linux`, test disk, photorec

Comment: I type a locate -i file name, then I get its adress, /home/my user name/my file, but how to operate it. I typed sudo fsck /dev/sdXY but I got sdXY Possibly non-existent device?

Comment: That means *myfile* is located at */home/my  user  name*. Check its the file you are looking or another with same name.

Comment: I have looked for it, I type find /home/my user name -name my file, it is located at .local /home/shukai-lab/.local/share/Trash/files/my file, but I didn't know why it was moved

Comment: Yes, My first option, look at Trash. It is located at center of left most side pane of nautilus. You can recover your folder from there.

Comment: Thank you very much, but I still didn't know how it happend

Comment: If everything O.K , upvote my answer and accept it. You may accidently pressed the delete button on your keyboard after selecting the folder.